# How to keep the database connection alive on the server regardless of the HttpServlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to understand how the `servlet` should work.

I have a Tomcat 8 running the web server.
I created a `servlet`, that extends the `HttpServlet` class.

```
public class CollectedItems extends HttpServlet {
    ...
}
```

There I have the `doGet` and `doPost` methods.
This class instance will be created, as soon as an `http` request is sent.

I want to be able to create another class that will maintain my DB connection once, and I will keep it alive instead, that in each call I will create these objects from scratch.

In a normal java application I would have the `main` method, that launch as soon as you run the program. How does it work in a `servlet`? Where should I put the class, that the main function start, as soon as the server is up?

The database was just an example, I'm looking for a place, where I can initialize my server objects.

Comment: think about a static singleton, or use DB connection pooling

Comment: where is the main method that has been launched located in the server side in that case?

Comment: call the singleton from your `doget`  if it is created it will not get created again.

Comment: Yeah thats true , just update my question , i'm looking for a place where i can initialize my server objects that the servlet would be able to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'm looking for a place where i can initialize my server objects

In that case consider using a ServletContextListener, this will be loaded when the application starts.
From here you can create a singleton object which can be accessible by all your servlets

Comment: It must be a good solution, since its the solution used by major frameworks such as Spring :-)

Comment: When dose the serveltContextListener childs are created ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is working like a charm :) http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-work-with-servletcontextlistener.html

Answer (score 1):

you can configure a servlet in web.xml,the tomcat will run the servlet when your application running, codes like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CollectedItems</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com......ClientActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CollectedItems</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CollectedItems</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```